# Oxyplot StringFormat

Tags: xamarin, oxyplot

I am using Oxyplot in Xamarin.

In my Oxyplot view, I want to show the time in the X Axis as `18h`.

In c# this would be formatted as `HH\h`, but `StringFormat = "HH\h"` doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution:

```
StringFormat = @"HH\h"
```